# How to Override Specflow feature CS code for ScenarioCleanup()

Tags: .net, specflow

Is it possible to write a new global method that will override the ScenarioCleanup() in my auto-generated specflow feature.cs file?

```
public virtual void ScenarioCleanup()
        {
            testRunner.CollectScenarioErrors();
        }
```

I would prefer that ScenarioCleanup() does not run.

My code is in .Net

The reason I need this is because ScenarioCleanup() is returning 'object not set to an instance of the object' error when I call a method from another project. Running this other project method from my step definition works fine, but when I run the test from the Feature file -> Step Definition -> other project method, I get the error.

My specflow project sits inside a large solution containing many projects that has huge amount of related dependencies. I cannot make changes to these other dev projects.

---

This is not the answer but the initial error message I receive. I.e. the reason I want to override ScenarioCleanup.

```
Test method ApplicationUnderTest.IntegrationTests.AutomationTests.Features._000_Stage5Feature.Stage5_Atester threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.HandleBlockSwitch(ScenarioBlock block)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.Then(String text, String multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword)
   at ApplicationUnderTest.IntegrationTests.AutomationTests.Features._000_Stage5Feature.Stage5(String role, String user, String row, String[] exampleTags) in 000_Stage5.feature: line 9
   at ApplicationUnderTest.IntegrationTests.AutomationTests.Features._000_Stage5Feature.Stage5_Atester() in 000_Stage5.feature.cs: line 0
```

Any suggestions why I am receiving this error in the first place?

Comment: It seems unusual that ScenarioCleanup would be the cause of the errors.  Is it possible that it has triggered these errors by cleaning up some of your resources?  Perhaps IDisposables or objects with Finalisers that aren't behaving well?  If so, avoiding clean up won't prevent them from going out of scope.

Comment: I agree it's unusual behaviour. The returned error also lists ScenarioCleanup() in the info. So I was able to comment out the ScenarioCleanup() method and then run my test and it passed successfully. But obviously this comment out was in the auto-generated faeture.cs and so it is regenerated after a project build.